# Evaluating the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}$

Tags: calculus

How do you evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}?$$

Comment: You could try to evaluate the limit of the logarithm of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we should be witty about how we write it. How about we consider instead the limit $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^x (x+1)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( \frac{x}{x+1} \right )^{x} * \frac{1}{x+1} $$

I think that this is suggestive of a proof?

Answer (score 13):

How about using squeeze theorem? Try squeezing this as $0 \leq \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}} \leq \frac{x^x}{x^{x+1}} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: +1 Very nice! I don't think you can get a simpler solution than this one.